# linear regression by multiple condition in dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, coefficients

Say I have 20 vehicles, each vehicle were tested 10 times, and within each test, there are multiple segments defined based on route distance driven.

I would like to get simple linear regression slopes for the regression on the height versus route distance, for each veh_id+test_id+segment combination.

Using `dplyr` package in R, I think something like this should work:

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
group_by (veh_id, test_id, segment) %>%
do(data.frame(mod = coef(lm(height ~ distance,data = .))[2])) %>%
left_join(dataset,.)
```

But the error is reported as:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)
>   :  0 (non-NA) cases

I looked back into my data, there are some NAs for the "height" variable...

Is there a way to execute the code by excluding those NAs in height?

Comment: add `na.action=na.exclude` within the lm function.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid excluding `NA`s in the `lm()` function. Instead, good practice is to separate the cleaning step from the modeling step.  For example, you can use the `drop_na()` function from the `tidyr` package in order to drop rows containing missing values from the dataset. Below I use the built-in `airquality` dataset as an example:

```
library(tidyr)
dataset <- airquality %>% drop_na()

> nrow(airquality) - nrow(dataset)
[1] 42
```